# How to create expander bar at right side of web page?

Tags: php, html, web, floating

I am currently trying to create "floating sidebars". By this I mean the social media share button you see in the link below: http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/instagram-post-notifications-news/

I want to create something similar: a div which is fixed on the right side of the edge (so at the end of the window) and is visible all the time.  If you click the div it can either expand to show additional content or it disappears.

I know how to solve this part, but the main problem is that my page is not full width (there are always spaces left on the left and right side).

I was thinking to use negative positions, but the problem is that they will only work when the width of the window does not get changed.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Please add tags to specify what technology/environment you are talking about. I *suppose* you are referring to websites?

Comment: Sorry, for that. Just added it